# Can not invoke possibly undefined object after checking with &&

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This has probably been asked before (please refer me if true) but I've been trying to invoke a function after checking for its existence with `&&`

```
interface IProps {
    primaryAction?: () => void;
}    
    
const Comp: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.primaryAction && (
        <Button onClick={() => props.primaryAction()}>
          Click
        </Button>
      )}
    </div>
    );
};
```

The TS compiler complains:

> Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Trick is to put it in its own variable before using it
````
const { primaryAction } = props;

{ primaryActions && ...
````

Comment: oh wow, that works. Any clue why?

Comment: Typescript isn't smart enough as yet :(. One day your approach will work I'm sure.

Comment: ^ I was wrong. See the answer below. Good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You did *not* check in the same scope where you use it. In theory, `props` could have had its content changed by the time your function runs.

Add this (terrible) code to your render function and you would get a runtime error on click:

```
setTimeout(() => props.primaryAction = undefined, 100)
```

This is the error that typescript is protecting you from. It's saying that it cannot guarantee the that your non-null check is still valid when you use that value.

This is why it's usually recommended to deconstruct props in functional components:

```
const Comp: React.FC<IProps> = ({ primaryAction }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {primaryAction && (
        <Button onClick={() => primaryAction()}>
          Click
        </Button>
      )}
    </div>
    );
};
```

Now you have *direct* reference to the value, and you know it can't be changed because no code outside could affect the assigned value without typescript noticing, because that would have to happen within this function.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOASQAUcwBnOAb1Ln7hgooFFACeAQQzAIlAPwAuOAAoAlHAC8APjgA3CMAAmAblIBfAXD4DSaWR3gBhXGCXJ0MAHQAxRwB5Wdg4dDRVuQWEQUUlpWTgzdW0eayIYAFcoShVrfj9DYF0tHIFuIRFxKRgZLIAyGuzLSz8AITSYGDjZRwAbYDQAaw1uNU0dMqiK2Mo1MyLGxp6+-uKmgHpW9tk5xtUzYr9V-MLi1VMzYyA)

Comment: Wow, thanks! This is great. I don't understand the scope part, though. I get that arguments are mutable, so assigning them to a const you can make sure that they aren't undefined. But I thought arguments live in the function scope.

Comment: When you validate a property of an object, typescript can't guarantee that validation for long. That object may be referenced in a totally different part of your application and it's properties could be changed, which may mean your check was invalidated. But you are validate that a variable has a value (not a property) typescript knows for sure if the local scope could possibly change that value or not since it can see all your assignments. if you added `setTimeout(() => primaryAction = undefined, 100)` to your function, you should see it error again. TS now knows it may be `undefined` again.